# chrome extension to run script on page load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm writing a chrome extension which should be capable of running a script on that page as soon as it has been loaded. I implemented the feature to run the code on clicking on extension icon but when I added code to run that script on page load its not working

Manifest file

```
 {
  "name": "",
   "description": "",
   "version": "1.0",

   "permissions": [
     "activeTab",
     "tabs"
    ],
   "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
    },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "",
  "default_icon": "6a00e3982283618833019affd3c028970c.png"
   },
  "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

js file:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
  function ( tabId, changeInfo, tab )
  { 
    if ( changeInfo.status === "complete" )
    {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      code: "console.log('dsff');"
    });
  }
});
```

but despite this my js is not running when ever user changes the page in a tab

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you registered a callback to **[`chrome.tabs.executeScript(...)`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript)** to catch any errors, e.g.:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: "console.log('dsff');" }, function() {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
         console.log("ERROR: " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    }
});
```

you would notice the following error:

> ERROR: Cannot access contents of url "...". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.

So, you need to add the appropriate **[host match pattern](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html)** to the `permissions` list in your manifest. E.g. to be able to inject code into any `http/https` page:

```
"permissions": ["*://*/*"]
```

---

Furthermore, if you omit the `tabId` argument of **[`chrome.tabs.executeScript(...)`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript)** it will apply to the currently active tab (which might defer from the one that fired the `onUpdated` event). So, also, make the following change:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: "console.log('dsff');" }, function() {...
```

Comment: I gave the permission but its still not working
by using 
      "permissions": ["*://*/*"]
it should work for file://
but when Its not giving me desired output also its not even showing output of callback function

Comment: @mebjas: See my updated answer for one more possible cause of unexpected behaviour. If it is still not working, check the console logs (of the background page **and** of the updated tab) for any errors. Also, use `chrome.runtime.lastError` (as illustrated in my answer) to catch any injection errors.

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you using same file (background.js) for both content and background script.

Content scripts can't use chrome.* api's

Comment: Added it to check if that was required to make script run on every page.
but it doesn't work even if I remove it @Prabu